# How to solve the problem with switching to the site in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I ran into a problem. Does not follow the link, opens the link as: **"data.,"**

> Google: 81.0.4044.129 
>   Chromedriver: 81.0.4044.69 
>   Selenium: 3.141.0 
>   Urllib3: 1.25.9 
>   Python: 3.8.1

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('httpd://www.browserstack.com')

name = input('Enter the name of user or group : ')
msg = input('Enter your message : ')
count = int(input('Enter the count : '))

input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')

user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
user.click()

msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2S1VP')

for i in range(count):
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_35EW6')
    button.click()
```

Comment: `https` perhaps ?

Comment: NO, don't working. I tried http,https, only www